# Subreport values are not displayed in main report

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have my main report which contains 1 subreport. When I run my main report the subreport values are not displayed in my main report, but when I run my subreport individually I can see the output in PDF format. Can anyone help me in fixing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

First see the connection with right click on the report and click on open subreport if its working then clik on the subreport go to the subreport property and see the parameter passed to the subreport is correct or not if not please pass properly. also see the parameter value required for the subreport is that comming from main report. 
Means : if your subreport require account_id = 5 the it must that main report passes the value 5 to the subreport.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the SubreportProcessingEventHandler and add the datasource.
Step 2: Check the properties of subreport.
       If it does not need any parameters from main report. Do not add any.
       The path of the repo